# DataStore - Models were generated with an unsupported version of codegen

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, codegen

I have a form where some values are taken and at the end some images are added through expo image picker. All of those informations are to be uploaded to AWS amplify so upon importing the models I suddenly receive a weird error I haven't seen before and it says
[image]

The moment I comment the line where I import the model it doesn't show that error but then I can't upload to AWS.

```
import { DataStore } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { House } from "../models";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming from Codegen version being outdated I guess so running `amplify upgrade` then `amplify codegen models` upgraded the CLI and updated the codegen version therefore solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was on Amplify CLI version 6.3.1 and `amplify upgrade` had no effect.
A simple reinstall did the trick: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install/